# Better structure for values of pairs to do faster lookup (in R)

Tags: r, database, matrix, lookup

Updated (once more) with intermediate results, see below!

## Background

I have a dataset (to simplifly, let's say it's) of people, where each combination (pair) has a value associated with them (let's say it's the number of years they've known each other). So for example say Samwell has known Jon for 2 years and Bran for 0 years, etc.:

```
      Jon Samwell Bran
Jon     NA   2    10 
Samwell 2    NA   0
Bran    10   0    NA
```

The real data is about a 1000x1000 matrix that needs to be updated on every iteration of a simulation that it is being used in, and there could be 100,000 iterations in run, and hundreds of runs. So speed is important.

### Problemo

I will need to look up these values, and the lookup can stem from either member of the pair (a non-computational analogue would be asking, "Hey Jon, how long have you known Bran?"), and also update these values more often than not. I could of course just use a similar matrix:

```
# R code
dat = matrix(c(NA,2,10,2,NA,0,10,0,NA), ncol=3)
row.names(dat) = c("Jon", "Samwell", "Bran")
colnames(dat) = c("Jon", "Samwell", "Bran")
# Jon -> Bran?
dat["Jon", "Bran"]
```

This works, but any time I update the info, I will need to update two values in the matrix, `["Jon", "Bran"]` and `["Bran", "Jon"]`. Also, it's the same value, so keeping it in two places seems redundant. I could use only one (e.g., lower) triangle of the matrix, but then the lookup should be ordered somehow, because:

```
      Jon Samwell Bran
Jon     NA   NA   NA 
Samwell 2    NA   NA
Bran    10   0    NA

dat["Jon", "Bran"] # returns NA...
```

I could number the people (or sort alphabetically) and then do something like

```
dat[max(1,3), min(1,3] # correctly returns 10
```

...but this too feels roundabout and probably slow to compute the min and max all the time (keep in mind, on the order of 100x100k times). Another option is a list that would hold triplets of such data (`dat2 = list(c("Jon", "Bran", 10), c("Jon", "Samwell", 2)`), and then use grep or whatever for lookup, but that does not seem like a viable idea either.

## Question

What I would need is a structure that allows me to call something like:

```
# pseudo R code
dataset[ "Jon", "Bran" ]       # returns 10
dataset[ "Bran", "Jon" ]       # returns the same, 10
dataset[ "Bran", "Jon" ] = 11  # changes value
dataset[ "Jon", "Bran" ]       # now returns 11
```

**What would be a good database structure (in R) for representing these relationships in such a way that I can quickly look up any value between any pair, and modify each pair when needed?**

## Update: intermediate comparison of approaches:

```
### Lower-triangle matrix approach
# simulate some data - using numbers instead of names for simplicity:
dataset = matrix(1:1e+06, 1000,1000)
dataset[upper.tri(dataset)] = NA

## My initial suggestion with min, max
f0 = function(r, c){ 
    dataset[max(r, c), min(r, c)]
}

## Approach with ifelse, is.na
f1 <- function(rowname, colname) {
    ifelse(is.na(dataset[rowname,colname]), dataset[colname, rowname], 
           dataset[rowname, colname])
}

## Approach with flipping the triangles
f1.1 <- function(m) {
    m[upper.tri(m)] <- t(m)[upper.tri(m)]
    return(m)
}

### Named vector approach 
# simulate some data first:
names=character(); length(names)=1e+06
dat = 1:1e+06
ix = 1
for(i in 1:1000){
    for(j in 1:1000){
        names[ix] = paste(i,j,sep=":")
        ix = ix+1
    }
}
names(dat) = names

# The Indexing Function
f2<-function(rowname,colname){
  ifelse(rowname>colname,
         paste(colname,rowname,sep=":"),
         paste(rowname,colname,sep=":"))
}  


### Testing time! ###

r = sample(1:100,100)
c = sample(1:100,100)
library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(f0 = for(i in 1:100){f0(r[i],c[i])},       # min, max
               f1 = for(i in 1:100){f1(r[i],c[i])},       # ifelse, is.na
               ft = for(i in 1:100){dataset = f1.1(dataset); dataset[r[i], c[i]]}, # triangles
               f2 = for(i in 1:100){dat[f2(r[i],c[i])]},  # named vector
               times=10 # only 10, but otherwise took too long
               )
```

The results:

```
Unit: microseconds
 expr          min           lq         mean       median           uq          max
   f0      225.355      229.818     263.1525      253.246      268.641      386.897
   f1      365.923      377.971      437.055      414.341      451.156      677.851
   ft     15252785     15316552     15566444     15448666     15589053     16657835
   f2 24486482.495 25188285.201     26106770 25428894.256 26610528.584 31256624.432
```

Update 29.03 with double write suggestion by @alexis_laz

```
# Suggestion to write to two locations in the matrix, so it could be accessed either way
f2x = function(r, c){ 
    dataset[r,c] = 100
    dataset[c,r] = 100
}

# Testing, this time a writing operation is included for comparison
microbenchmark(f0  = for(i in 1:100){dataset[r,c] = 100; f0(r[i],c[i])}, #original min,max
               f2x = for(i in 1:100){f2x(r[i],c[i])    ; dataset[r,c]},  # write to two slots
               times=10, unit = "us")

Unit: microseconds
 expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq        max 
   f0  25843.98  25922.07  30032.01  26515.36  33039.72   49811.93 
  f2x 590426.03 680729.11 778541.39 706079.99 785109.53 1178319.16 
# nope, this does not improve over the writing/accessing the lower triangle
```

...so my naive lower-triangle-matrix-min-max indexing approach still wins. Is this really the best answer?

Comment: You could go full OOP on this, I suppose, and turn to S4, reference classes or R6 objects to define the structure you want.

Comment: In each iteration only one pair is updated? It might be more worthy to find a way to update multiple pairs; e.g. by, somehow, collecting the pairs at the end of the iteration and use `dataset[cbind(people1, people2)] = years` than `dataset[person1, person2] = years`?

Comment: @alexis_laz yes, one iteration = one interaction between any two agents, so their pair value gets updated

Comment: If you keep your structure as a "n x n" matrix, then, I guess, you could just store each value in both lower and upper matrix (and in your function assign to both places) and subset without using min/max; since the structure is saved it won't make a difference if you have `NA`s or numbers. On the other hand, you could store only the lower half in memory but, then, subsetting and assigning will be more complicated and time consuming. Either way, it might be more worthy to try and find a way to update multiple indices/pairs and not one per iteration.

Comment: @alexis_laz - I ran a comparison, see updated question (in short: thanks for throwing another idea; this does not seem to improve performance though).

Comment: @joran Perhaps you'd like to elaborate on this in the form of an answer? :)

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of approach see [Copy upper triangle to lower triangle for several matrices in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26166569/copy-upper-triangle-to-lower-triangle-for-several-matrices-in-a-list). If you only want to setup the lower diagonal, you could have a function copy these values to the upper diagonal.

```
dat = matrix(c(NA,2,10,NA,NA,0,NA,NA,NA),3,3)
dat

#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]   NA   NA   NA
# [2,]    2   NA   NA
# [3,]   10    0   NA

f <- function(m) {
    m[upper.tri(m)] <- t(m)[upper.tri(m)]
    m
}

f(dat)

#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]   NA    2   10
# [2,]    2   NA    0
# [3,]   10    0   NA
```

Another idea would be

```
f <- function(rowname, colname) {
    ifelse(is.na(dataset[rowname,colname]), dataset[colname, rowname], 
           dataset[rowname, colname])
}

f("Jon", "Bran") # same as f("Bran", "Jon")
```

This might be the best way to go but assumes that if dataset["Jon", "Bran"] is NA then dataset["Bran", "Jon"] won't be.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a matrix, you can store in a named number list:

```
dat<-c(2,10,0)
names(dat)<-c("Jon:Samwell","Bran:Jon","Bran:Samwell")

> dat
 Jon:Samwell     Bran:Jon Bran:Samwell
           2           10            0

### The Indexing Function
f<-function(rowname,colname){
  ifelse(rowname>colname,
         paste(colname,rowname,sep=":"),
         paste(rowname,colname,sep=":"))
}
```

Testing:

```
> dat[f("Jon","Bran")]
Bran:Jon
      10

> dat[f("Bran","Jon")]
Bran:Jon
      10

> dat[f("Bran","Jon")] = 11

> dat[f("Jon","Bran")]
Bran:Jon
      11

## Can accept list too:
> dat[f(c("Jon","Samwell"),c("Bran","Jon"))]
   Bran:Jon Jon:Samwell 
         11           2
```

Check the speed:

```
> set.seed(1)
> a<-sample(c("Jon","Samwell","Bran"),1000000,replace=T)
> b<-sample(c("Jon","Samwell","Bran"),1000000,replace=T)
> system.time(out<-dat[f(a,b)])
   user  system elapsed 
  1.212   0.028   1.244
```

Comment: I have to say, the premise looks attractive (and also intuitive), but unfortunately it's too slow to keep pasting things together (see updated Q).